# How to hide console while running a batch file on windows

Tags: batch-file

In my project i am using the btach file to start the exe file. This batch file is triiggered from an external source(may be another exe). It works as expected. But it opens a console. We don't want any conosole to displayed. 
Is there any way where we can hide this console. 
We tried with -- console suppress, could not get the desired results.

Comment: Run it from a vbvscript instead

Comment: Fine. I will try this.

Comment: We solved this via a AutoIT script(https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done as batch files use the cmd program to execute the desired code. All i can suggest is to make the code as quick and sharp as possible to have it on screen for minimal time, or execute the code using a third party program or a different coding program all-together.